# Unable to use Eclipse's Scrapbook inside an Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

It is okay when I create a Scrapbook inside a normal Eclipse Java project, but when I create a Scrapbook inside an Android project, and enter a simple code like

```
System.out.println("foo");
```

It said "**Unable to launch the Scrapbook VM**"

As this method does not involve any Android library, why this does not work?

Comment: Are you trying to print out system message? you can use toast or a debugger message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this problem today and i'm afraid that there is no way to run a scrapbook into an Android project, since i can't find a solution anywhere (and i've been looking for it for some hour).

I even tried to change the Runtime JRE for the scrapbook (right-click on scrapbook file -> properties -> Scrapbook Runtime -> "Runtime JRE") since default JRE reports "Project JRE(undefined)". Nothing changed.

I'm writing this because i hope to save time to some other person.

Comment: Thanks. This sucks but your post has saved me a lot of time

Comment: You can not use scrapbook in java project

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new scrapbook page in android projects. Use Display view instead "in a scrapbook type fashion".
source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Comment: If you are not debugging the application you can't use display there but its not the case of scrapbook

Comment: you right, this feature works only while debugging application

Comment: after stopping at breakpoint you can write arbitrary code at display window and 1 - inspect result, 2- execute (change values on the fly)

Comment: you can use watch to write arbitrary code but only at break mode